# select multiple head() and tail() values in a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector as follows:

```
v <- c(1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,NA,NA,NA,NA,27,25,30,41,NA,NA)
```

How can I extract the values 1, 9, 27 and 41 (i. e. the first and last position of each subset without NAs)?

I thought about using `head(v, 1)` and `tail(v, 1)` in combination. However I don't have an idea how to 'stop' at the NAs and restart again after them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a grouping variable with `rleid` based on the logical vector (`is.na(v)`), use that in `tapply` to select the first and last values of each group, `unlist` the `list` output, remove the NA elements with `na.omit` and remove the attributes with `c`.

```
library(data.table)
c(na.omit(unlist(tapply(v, rleid(is.na(v)), function(x) c(x[1], 
                                  x[length(x)])), use.names=FALSE)))
#[1]  1  9 27 41
```

---

Or another option is `rle` from `base R`

```
v[with(rle(!is.na(v)), {
         i1 <- cumsum(lengths)
         i2 <- lengths[values]
         c(rbind(i1[values] - i2 + 1 , i1[values]))
   })]
#[1]  1  9 27 41
```

Comment: Thanks to your answers + explanations I get more and more into data.table :)

Comment: This selects single non-NA elements twice. Try it on `c(v, 30)`

Comment: @sirallen That could be solved by wrapping with `unique` and I am not sure about the behavior for those cases as it is not explained in the question

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution via base R could be to `split` based on `NA` entries in the vector, `lapply` the `head` and `tail` functions and remove `NA`'s, i.e.

```
ind <- unname(unlist(lapply(split(v, cumsum(c(1, diff(is.na(v)) != 0))), function(i) 
                                                           c(head(i, 1), tail(i, 1)))))

ind[!is.na(ind)]

#[1]  1  9 27 41
```

Comment: This selects single non-NA elements twice. Try it on `c(v, 30)`

Comment: Maybe the OP wants it like that...? It is not explained in the question

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution:

```
x = na.omit( v[is.na(c(NA,diff(v))) | is.na(c(diff(v),NA))] )

> as.numeric(x)
# [1]  1  9 27 41
```

Comment: coming back to this question for another example, which has **duplicate entries**, your answer works perfectly!